# Signature Verifier returns false on checking with itself

Tags: java, security

I can't understand why the code bellow  returns `false` on checking with itself?

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.*;


public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    KeyPair keyPair;
    String data = "test";

        try {

          KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
          keyPairGen.initialize(512);
          keyPair =  keyPairGen.genKeyPair();

          Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
          sign.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
          sign.update(data.getBytes());

          byte[] encoded = sign.sign();

          sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
          sign.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
          sign.update(encoded);
          System.out.println("Checked: "  + sign.verify(encoded)); // Testing with itself returns false????

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

There is a problem with the Private/Public keys?
I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the wrong thing, change this line

```
sign.update(encoded);
```

to  this

```
sign.update(data.getBytes());
```

after getting the PublicKey.